# Предложение для FAQ. Прошу администраторов принять участие

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено

Поскольку дело не трогается с места, как обещал, предлагаю свой вариант базовых правил, чтобы не было нелепой копии программистского StackOverflow. Я сделал грубый и усечённый перевод аналогичного раздела с SO RussianLanguage.

Предлагаю всем публиковать уточнения в виде ответов в этой теме.

**ВЕРСИЯ НОМЕР ДВА. Учтены пожелания.**

**О чём можно спрашивать?**

Этот сайт для тех, кто заинтересован в изучении русского языка - как для любителей, так и для профессионалов. Для тех, кому русский язык является родным и для тех, кому он всего третий иностранный.
Мы приветствуем вопросы о грамматике и синтаксисе, о происхождении и значении слов и выражений, об использовании тех или иных конструкций в современном русском языке или языке прежних времён.

Пожалуйста, прежде чем задавать вопрос, [тут ссылка на поиск, не понял, как вставлять]проверьте[/конец ссылки], не спрашивал ли то же самое кто-нибудь раньше. Вы можете ответить даже на свой собственный вопрос, если на самом деле приложили усилия и нашли ответ уже после того, как задали вопрос.

**Политика**

Воздержитесь от вопросов с явной политический окраской. "В" или "на" Украину подробно рассмотрено в сети много раз. Если Вы не можете задать вопрос о русском языке, в котором русского языка было бы больше, чем политики, не задавайте его совсем.

**Опросы**

Темы-"опросы" (например, какой из трёх вариантов фразы правильнее) допускаются, если Вы действительно ищите доводы за и против, основанные на правилах русского языка. Вопросы же умозрительные ("А если бы я сказал так, что бы вы подумали") здесь не нужны.

**Что хотел сказать автор?**

Вопросы о мыслях автора, отношении к персонажам, раскрытии их характеров и мотивов поступков, как и вообще литературоведческие вопросы - не для этого сайта. Синие занавески пусть остаются синими, а поток пусть ревёт без девушки.

**Сочинения**

Здесь не помогают писать сочинения. Если у Вас ничего не получается, обратитесь к друзьям или преподавателю. Или для разминки сочините фантастический рассказ на полстраницы.

**Мат**

Обсуждение табуированной лексики допустимо в разумных пределах. Не надо убеждать посетителей сайта, что вы можете построить длинную фразу, где все слова происходят от одного корня.

**Переводы**

Такие вопросы не запрещены, но помните - это не ресурс для переводчиков. Вопросы с очевидным ответом будут закрываться. При этом вопросы о переводе *с любого языка на руский* допустимы, если подробно разъяснено значение исходного выражения, а переводы *с русского на другой язык* всё же лучше задавать на профильном сайте соответствующего языка.

**Ресурсы в сети**

Обычно такие вопросы не поощряются, потому что представляют из себя просто список ссылок, которые почти всегда легко найти поиском в сети. Убедитесь, что спрашиваете о чём-то действительно редком и малоизвестном, если хотите задать такой вопрос.

**Значение одного-единственного слова**

Да, если Вы перед этим честно поискали в сети и не смогли найти устраивающий Вас ответ.

**ВЕРСИЯ НОМЕР ТРИ. Учтены пожелания. Почему участие принимают только два человека - остаётся загадкой.**

**О чём можно спрашивать?**

Этот сайт для тех, кто заинтересован в изучении русского языка - как для любителей, так и для профессионалов. Для тех, кому русский язык является родным и для тех, кому он всего третий иностранный.
Мы приветствуем вопросы о грамматике и синтаксисе, о происхождении и значении слов и выражений, об использовании тех или иных конструкций в современном русском языке или языке прежних времён. 
Вопросы, начинающиеся с "*почему?*" допускаются только если ответ предполагает указания на прямую причинно-следственную связь.

Пожалуйста, прежде чем задавать вопрос, [тут ссылка на поиск, не понял, как вставлять]проверьте[/конец ссылки], не спрашивал ли то же самое кто-нибудь раньше. Вы также можете ответить на свой собственный вопрос (в том числе и сразу же, при публикации).

**Политика**

Воздержитесь от вопросов с явной политический окраской. "В" или "на" Украину подробно рассмотрено в сети много раз. Если Вы не можете задать вопрос о русском языке, в котором русского языка было бы больше, чем политики, не задавайте его совсем.

**Опросы**

Темы с вариантами ответов (например, какой из трёх вариантов фразы правильнее) допускаются, если Вы действительно ищите доводы за и против, основанные на правилах русского языка. Опросы же, т.е. темы, которые имеют целью выяснить только лишь субъективное мнение опрашиваемых здесь не нужны. Затейте голосование в какой-нибудь социальной сети. Там и ответов будет больше.

**Что хотел сказать автор?**

Вопросы о мыслях автора, отношении к персонажам, раскрытии их характеров и мотивов поступков, как и вообще литературоведческие вопросы - не для этого сайта. Синие занавески пусть остаются синими, а поток пусть ревёт без девушки. Вопросы об особенностях авторского стиля, употреблении им странных слов, необычном синтаксисе или "почему стихи лесенкой" вполне подходят сайту и принимаются.

**Умозрительные вопросы**

Запрещены. Вопросы схоластического или казуистического характера больше подходят для расслабленной личной беседы. Не требуйте объяснений своим же выдумкам. Также сайту не подходят вопросы навроде: "*А вот гр. Разэтакий Такой Сякоевич в 4-и томе своих ненаписанных записок предлагает писать корова через Ѣ. Что вы об этом думаете?*"

**Сочинения и олимпиады**

Здесь не помогают писать сочинения и, по-честному, не должны помогать делать домашние задания. Если у Вас ничего не получается, обратитесь к друзьям или преподавателю. Или для разминки сочините фантастический рассказ на полстраницы. Если хотите задать вопрос с олимпиады (а они интереснее хотя бы тем, что сложнее) - предоставьте убедительные доказательства, что это вопрос с завершившейся олимпиады.

**Мат**

Обсуждение табуированной лексики допустимо в разумных пределах. Не надо убеждать посетителей сайта, что вы можете построить длинную фразу, где все слова происходят от одного корня.

**Визуальная информация**

Постарайтесь не задавать вопросы в форме картинок, если только Вам не нужно привести факсимиле текста или схему. Даже новгородские берестяные грамоты есть в сети в виде текстов. Помните также, что рассматривание приложенных картинок с мобильных устройств может быть очень некомфортным.

**Переводы**

Такие вопросы не запрещены, но помните - это не ресурс для переводчиков. Вопросы с очевидным ответом будут закрываться. При этом вопросы о переводе *с любого языка на руский* допустимы, если подробно разъяснено значение исходного выражения, а переводы *с русского на другой язык* всё же лучше задавать на профильном сайте соответствующего языка.

**Ресурсы в сети**

Обычно такие вопросы не поощряются, потому что представляют из себя просто список ссылок, которые почти всегда легко найти поиском в сети. Убедитесь, что спрашиваете о чём-то действительно редком и малоизвестном, если хотите задать такой вопрос.

**Значение одного-единственного слова**

Да, если Вы перед этим честно поискали в сети и не смогли найти устраивающий Вас ответ. Бывают же такие слова...

Comment: hinotf, это полная версия или наброски? Понимаете, правила о переводах и очевидных ответах не слишком актуалены. Первое что надо отразить. Запрет/разрешение: 1. политически окрашенных тем (с оценками). 2. тем-опросов, где ответ строится на личном мнении 3. бессмысленных вопросов типа "а как понимать, что хотел сказать автор" и "как вы относитесь к личной жизни князя Болконского" 4. Литературные вопросы, пусть даже по произведениям на русском языке (по счастью или несчастью, таковых стало много меньше) (продолжение следует)

Comment: @behemothus это заготовка, потому что позор и мрак кромешний то, что сейчас размещено в соответствующем разделе :-)

Comment: 5. Школьные и институтские д/з и сочинения (тут я категорически против) 6. Олимпиадные вопросы текущих олимпиад  7. Прочие умозрительные, казуистические и мусорные вопросы, ответы на которые очевидно не приносят практической пользы  (А если бы я сказал так, что бы вы подумали)  8. Лингвистическая Экспертиза 9. Обсуждение табуированной лексики 10. ну и вот где-то здесь - переводы... Это не всё, что-то само отпадает, что-то ещё появится. А, да, "авторские" (см. мой про Бабариху) и шуточно-развлекательные вопросы типа шарад.

Comment: Ну вот я вам дал свою заготовку ))). Вернее план.  Если бы я знал ответы и имел бы власть их претворить в жизнь я бы, конечно, сам написал.

Comment: Вечером обдумаю и допишу.

Comment: Да, а адресовать-то "в первую очередь" надо не мне, а администратору сайта. Я тут человек маленький, пусть и старейший.

Comment: По форме - замечательно. По содержанию есть мелкие вопросы, но я их забываю, пока читаю. Я перечитаю на свежую голову - восполню.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky, здесь требуется ваше участие.

Comment: Да, Николай тут нужен. А я вот уже думаю, не сократить ли все это на 2/3 примерно? Или сделать лайт-версию. Километровые ФАКи все равно никто не читает, увы.

Comment: @hinotf Как я понимаю, это предложение внести изменения в http://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, верно?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да! А то там ерунда какая-то. Текст, на мой взгляд, уже подходящего качества. За основу надо брать версию 3, только как минимум поправить там ссылку на поиск (второй абзац).

Comment: @hinotf Здорово! Для полноты картины, я добавил описание со старого сайта. Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на ответ. Как только финальный вариант справки будет готов, сразу можно будет добавить!

Comment: @hinotf [Проверяйте!](http://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). И большое спасибо за инициативу! Возможно, на ваш взгляд можно улучшить еще какую-то страницу справочного центра?

Comment: На мой взгляд - неплохо. Спасибо всем участникам. Другие страницы тоже посмотрю.

Answer (score 3):

В общем то, что могу уже сейчас сформулировать

> Опросы
>
> Темы-"опросы" (например, какой из трёх вариантов фразы правильнее)
> допускаются, если Вы действительно ищите доводы за и против,
> основанные на правилах русского языка. Вопросы же умозрительные ("А
> если бы я сказал так, что бы вы подумали") здесь не нужны.

Не понял идею. Для меня темы-опросы это темы, которые исключительно имеют целью выяснить субъективное мнение опрашиваемых. Если даже потом навести какую-то статистику, ценность подобного весьма сомнительна. И я не знаю, нужны ли они тут ("не знаю" - это даже с учетом опыта). У Вас, видимо, о чем-то другом, что тоже, возможно, имеет смысл закрепить в правилах, но я не очень понимаю, что это.

> Вопросы о мыслях автора, отношении к персонажам, раскрытии их характеров и >мотивов поступков, как и вообще литературоведческие вопросы - не для этого >сайта.

Вы уверены? Может и так, но это надо понять. Я точно против, если эти вопросы предполагается рассматривать в разрезе школьных сочинений. А в остальном - шут знает, ведь тут могут быть завязаны вопросы стилистики, жанровости, авторской грамматики, да много еще чего.

> Значение одного-единственного слова
>
> Да, если Вы перед этим честно поискали в сети и не смогли найти >устраивающий Вас ответ.

А так ли это?! Надо ли так ставить вопрос? Не знаю.
(+)
Вопросы с текущих олимпиад - запретить однозначно.
Вообще вопросы олимпиадного характера хорошо бы ограничить только теми, на которые есть ссылка, доказывающая, что вопрос старый. Иначе это хуже чем домашнее задание.
(++)
Умозрительные вопросы - запретить.
Поясню. Под такими вопросами я понимаю вопросы схоластического или казуистического характера. Пишет человек какую-нибудь абракадабру - и начинает требовать, чтобы её объяснили, или, того хуже, на её основании опровергает науку.
(++++)
О вопросах интерпретации мнений. Вы ограничились литературоведческими вещами, я же ставил (или хотел поставить) тему шире.
Для меня это вопросы типа *"А вот гр. Разэтакий Такой Сякоевич в 4-м томе своих ненаписанных записок предлагает писать корова через ять. Что вы об этом думаете?"* Смысл такого обсуждения - только карму себе набить.
Но бывает, что автор плохо формулирует, не хотелось бы вместе с водой выплеснуть и ребенка.
(+++++)
Вот еще. Я бы вообще запретил вопросы, начинающиеся "с почему?", если ответ не предполагает указания на прямую причинно-следственную связь. Например, "Почему кофе мужского рода, а пальто - среднего?"  Единственный разумный ответ на такой вопрос "А по кочану!". Так уж сложилось, нет на такие вопросы четкого ответа.

Я не могу это все сформулировать в виде конкретных "поправок" к документу, да еще в вашем стиле. Поэтому даю только замечания.

Comment: В первом сообщении темы создана версия номер три. Жалко, что администраторы ничего не пишут.

Answer (score 3):

Добавление. Только вот сейчас вспомнил.
Здесь или в другом месте надо добавить Фак по ответам.

Но в вопросы тоже стоит добавить (подумайте как, у Вас хорошо получается).

**Визуальная информация.**
Постарайтесь не задавать вопросы в форме картинок, если только вам не нужно привести факсимиле текста или схему. Пишите и цитируйте текстом, по возможности - с ссылками на источник. Картинки же только тормозят работу, да и те, кто сможет ответить и те, кто захочет задать подобный вопрос, гораздо быстрее найдут ваш вопрос по словам, а не по картинкам.

(Точно так же не стоит злоупотреблять картинками в ответах и комментариях).

Comment: Сделано. Часть про ответы пока писать не буду, ещё подумаю.

Answer (score 3):

Во времена, когда Русский язык работал на старой платформе Сети Знаний, сайт имел следующую страничку «о сайте».

> Русский язык - это сайт вопросов и ответов по русскому языку. Здесь нет назойливой и кричащей рекламы. Здесь по существу спрашивают и отвечают на широкий круг вопросов по самым разным темам: орфографии, пунктуации, этимологии, стилистике русского языка.
>
> Поскольку русский язык не стоит на месте и все время развивается, нужно изучать новое. И зачастую, когда сталкиваешься с чем-нибудь незнакомым, хорошо спросить знающего человека, который подскажет, где смотреть и что искать.
>
> Сайт совместно редактируется сообществом ваших коллег - филологов, лингвистов и вообще мастеров слова. Если вы увидите, что вопрос задан неудачно, ответа нет или он есть, но на вопрос не отвечает, вы можете исправить его к лучшему. Это поможет многим вашим товарищам, которые позднее придут на сайт. Более того, если вы хотите поделится знанием, которое можно выразить в форме вопроса и ответа, вы всегда можете задать вопрос и ответить на него сами.
>
> В чем особенность этого сайта? Ведь сколько форумов по русскому языку в сети... Главное - это те люди, которые принимают участие в жизни сайта. Среди них и начинающие изучение специальности, и опытные профессионалы высокого класса.  Кроме того, особенный дизайн проекта существенно повышает удобство работы с сайтом. В [справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/faq/) и [блоге](http://blog.stackoverflow.ru/) Сети Знаний подробно объясняется специфика  сайта. Присоединяйтесь!

Так же на сайте был FAQ

> - В чем особенность сайта Русский язык?
> - Почему вопросы идут сплошным потоком, без деления на разделы?
> - Как показать интересующие и скрыть неинтересующие меня вопросы?
> - Как получать обновления по интересующим меня темам?
> - Что означают цифры слева от заголовка вопроса?
> - Какие вопросы стоит задавать?
> - Какие вопросы не стоит задавать?
> - Что делать, если на мой вопрос не отвечают?
> - Как принять ответ?
> - Как форматировать текст в редакторе?
> - Нужно ли регистрироваться, чтобы спрашивать и отвечать?
> - Как задавать вопросы?
> - Как работает система репутации?
> - Что такое граватар?
> - Что такое визитка?
> - Могут ли другие участники править мои вопросы и ответы?
> - Что такое "общие" вопросы и ответы?
> - Забыт пароль, не срабатывает OpenID - в итоге не зайти на сайт, что делать?
> - Как оставить отзыв, задать вопрос, сделать предложение по сайту?
> - Как поделиться сайтом с другом?
> - У вас еще остались вопросы?
>
> ### В чем особенность сайта Русский язык?
>
> Чтобы лучше понять особенность сайта Русский язык, полезно прочитать
>   [блог](http://blog.hashcode.ru): в статьях дневника подробно раскрываются все существенные
>   стороны жизни проекта. Особенно важны нижеприведенные черты.
>
> - Общение на сайте происходит в формате вопросов и ответов. Этот формат удобен, поскольку сосредотачивает внимание на проблеме (вопрос)
>     и ее решении (ответ), в то время как длинные многостраничные дискуссии
>     имеют свойство размывать суть проблемы.
> - Сообщения на сайте могут редактироваться не только их авторами, но и всеми участниками с достаточным количеством очков уважения. В ряде
>     случаев правки могут быть очень значительными.
> - Сайт покрывает все без исключения предметные области, которые включает в себя языкознание. Чтобы не утонуть в таком многообразии,
>     темы разделяются и классифицируются не по разделам, а по меткам.
> - Модерация сайта происходит во многом автоматически, путем голосования за вопросы, ответы и комментарии.
> - Сайт поддерживает разнообразные способы поиска и сортировки необходимой информации.
>
> ### Почему вопросы идут сплошным потоком, без деления на разделы?
>
> Русский язык разбивает вопросы по категориям на основе меток. Это
>   гораздо более мощный и одновременно гибкий подход, нежели традиционный
>   форумный. Метки характеризуют специфику вопроса по:
>
> - разделу языкознания (орфография, морфология, ..)
> - по дисциплине (филология, лингвистика)
> - и так далее.
>
> Подробнее про метки на Русском языке - в статье дневника ["Метки как
>   разделы"](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_02.html).
>
> ### Как показать интересующие и скрыть неинтересующие меня вопросы?
>
> Что посмотреть вопросы одной тематики, кликните по соответствующей
>   метке, например, орфография или пунктуация, и вы увидите поток
>   сообщений, соответствующий этой метке. Вы можете еще более сузить
>   поток сообщений, кликнув по дополнительной метке в списке связанных
>   меток. Таким образом можно выбрать до пяти меток одновременно.
>
> После регистрации справа сверху появятся поля ввода [интересующих и
>   игнорируемых](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_09.html) меток.
>
> - Если добавить в игнорируемые метки те, вопросы по которым вас не интересуют, и обновить страницу, то все вопросы с этой меткой будут
>     спрятаны.
> - Если добавить в интересующие метки те, вопросы по которым вас интересуют, и обновить страницу, то все вопросы с этой меткой будут
>     подсвечены. Кроме того, в разделе вопросов без ответов можно выбрать
>     сортировку "мои метки", при которой будут показаны только вопросы,
>     содержащие интересующие метки.
>
> Чтобы система отбора вопросов на основе меток работала эффективно,
>   модераторы Русского языка периодически меняют (разбивают, объединяют,
>   удаляют, добавляют и переименовывают) метки.
>
> ### Как получать обновления по интересующим меня темам?
>
> Есть два варианта:
>
> 1. Лента новостей. Если необходимо отслеживать обновления по интересующим меткам, нужно кликнуть по выбранной метке, - и рядом с
>      заголовком потока вопросов будет значок RSS. Если необходимо
>      отслеживать обновления по интересующему вопросу, нужно зайти в
>      выбранный вопрос, - и справа снизу под связанными метками будет значок
>      RSS.
> 2. Почтовые уведомления. Чтобы подписаться на почтовые уведомления, необходимо зарегистрироваться. Профиль пользователя позволяет в
>      широких пределах настраивать виды уведомлений, а также
>      отключать/включать их при необходимости.
>
> ### Что означают цифры слева от заголовка вопроса?
>
> Голоса отображают оценку качества вопроса участниками сайта:
>
> - если цифра отрицательная, то вопрос - плохого качества и не заслуживает внимания (при значении -5 вопрос может быть удален);
> - если цифра - ноль, то вопрос - нормального качества;
> - если цифра положительная, то вопрос - отличного качества и его стоит посмотреть и возможно ответить.
>
> Ответы отображают текущее количество ответов на вопрос:
>
> - если цифра - в белом квадрате, то принятого ответа нет;
> - если цифра - в зеленом квадрате, то принятый ответ есть.
>
> Просмотры отображают текущее количество просмотров.
>
> ### Какие вопросы стоит задавать?
>
> Русский язык - это сайт вопросов и ответов, посвященный русскому языку. И если ваш
>   вопрос относится
>
> - выбору слов,
> - этимологии слов,
> - особенностям диалектов,
> - произношениям слов,
> - правописанию слов,
> - и т.д.
>
> то Русский язык - это удачное место, чтобы задать ваш вопрос.
>
> Используйте поиск, чтобы найти ответ на интересующий вас вопрос. В
>   современных обозревателях, чтобы быстрее набирать запросы, можно
>   задействовать горячие клавиши: Tab - чтобы попасть в строку ввода,
>   Enter - чтобы отправить запрос.
>
> Вы всегда можете задать вопрос и ответить на него сами, если вы
>   чувствуете, что знание, которым вы хотите поделиться, будет полезно
>   другим. Это равносильно публикации статьи в блоге, оформленной как
>   вопрос и ответ.
>
> ### Какие вопросы не стоит задавать?
>
> Не стоит задавать вопросы-опросы, где каждый ответ является верным,
>   сайт - не подходящее место для статистических исследований и
>   реальной ценности подобные темы не имеют.
>
> Не стоит задавать вопросы, предполагающие спорные и субъективные
>   ответы. Не стоит использовать ответ, чтобы задать уточняющий вопрос:
>   для этого есть комментарии. Не стоит просить сделать за вас курсовую
>   или любое другое [учебное задание](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_16.html), но вполне допустимо задать
>   вопрос, связанный с изучением русского языка.
>
> Не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за деньги
>   какую-либо работу, связанную с написанием или проверкой текста: сайт
>   не является фриланс-биржей. В частности, не допускаются вопросы
>
> - ответ на которые сразу находится в словаре, например, "Как пишется слово "арбуз": орбуз или арбуз?";
> - смысл которых которых сводится к проверке грамотности элементарного текста, например, "Правильно ли написана фраза,
>     исправьте ошибки, пожалуйста?";
> - которые являются домашними заданиями учащихся начальной и средней школы.
>
> Не стоит создавать темы с объявлениями о вакансиях в общем потоке
>   вопросов: в свое время будет создан специальный инструмент для поиска
>   работы и подбора кадров.
>
> Не стоит задавать вопросы и давать ответы, являющиеся рекламой или
>   продвижением какого-либо товара или услуги. Если вы хотите рассказать
>   о себе, своей работе или своем сайте, вы можете сделать это на
>   странице своего профиля: он специально создан для этих целей.
>
> ### Что делать, если на мой вопрос не отвечают?
>
> Первым делом убедитесь, что вопрос задан [качественно](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_8123.html). Проверьте
>   правильность [выбора](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_15.html) меток: многие участники просматривают только
>   вопросы с интересующими их метками. Проверьте грамотность текста и
>   [оформление](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/04/blog-post_22.html) кода. Если возможно, исправьте недочеты; это улучшит
>   читаемость текста и поднимет тему наверх. Если есть обновления или
>   уточнения, добавьте их в вопрос.
>
> Если вы задаете вопрос не первый раз, обратите внимание на процент
>   принятых (галочка слева) вами ответов. Чем меньше это число, тем
>   меньше вероятность получить ответ на вопрос.
>
> Помните, что сайт вопросов и ответов - это не служба (сервис)
>   поддержки, это площадка с открытым доступом для общения всех
>   заинтересованных в тематике сайта. Знатоки отвечают на вопрос, если
>   он читаем, понятен и интересен. И это задача автора - сделать вопрос
>   читаемым, понятным и интересным.
>
> ### Как принять ответ?
>
> После того, как другие участники ответили на ваш вопрос, нужно
>   просмотреть ответы и 1) проголосовать за полезные с вашей точки
>   зрения, 2) принять лучший, тот, который вам действительно помог. Очень
>   важно голосовать за ответы и принимать их, не забывайте об этом.
>
> ### Как форматировать текст в редакторе?
>
> Русский язык использует редактор Markdown. Поначалу он непривычен, но
>   потом - очень удобен. Подробную инструкцию по использованию можно
>   посмотреть [по ссылке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/markdown_help/).
>
> ### Нужно ли регистрироваться, чтобы спрашивать и отвечать?
>
> Да, нужно. Но вам не нужно придумывать имя и пароль, если у вас уже
>   есть OpenID: вы можете использовать свою учетную запись Яндекс,
>   Google, В Контакте, Facebook и другие для авторизации. Подробнее про
>   регистрацию - в статье дневника ["Регистрация и авторизация"](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post.html).
>
> ### Как задавать вопросы?
>
> Как только вы задали вопрос, он появляется на главной странице. Другие
>   участники замечают ваше сообщение и начинают отвечать на него. Если
>   ваш вопрос недостаточно ясен, то под ним появятся уточняющие
>   комментарии.
>
> Вам стоит периодически проверять состояние вашего вопроса. Если есть
>   уточняющие комментарии, нужно исправлять вопрос так, чтобы он был
>   более понятен.
>
> Если ответы действительно помогают, нужно голосовать за них. Таким
>   образом, лучшие ответы будут подниматься вверх (по умолчанию ответы
>   сортируются по голосам).
>
> Когда вы выберете ответ, который наиболее полезен вам, нужно принять
>   его. Это покажет другим участникам, что вы получили хороший ответ на
>   ваш вопрос.
>
> ### Как работает система репутации?
>
> Когда вопрос или ответ получает голос за, участнику, который оставил
>   сообщение, даются очки, которые в сумме определяются как "уважение".
>   Эти очки отражают меру доверия к участнику. Чем больше доверие к
>   участнику, тем больше возможностей модерировать сайт он имеет.
>   Минимальные требования по очкам уважения в настоящий момент (в будущем
>   они могут быть усилены) таковы:
>
> - голос за: 15,
> - голос против: 100,
> - тревога: 15,
> - ответ на свой вопрос: 50,
> - создание комментария: 50,
> - одобрение комментария: 15,
> - загрузка файла: 60,
> - создание метки: 250,
> - закрытие своего вопроса: 250,
> - переоткрытие своего вопроса: 500,
> - изменение меток чужого вопроса: 500,
> - правка общего сообщения: 750,
> - перевод сообщения в общие: 2000,
> - правка чужого сообщения: 2000,
> - закрытие чужого сообщения: 3000,
> - удаление чужого комментария: 2000,
> - преобразование ответа в комментарий: 2000,
> - преобразование комментария в ответ: 2000,
> - преобразование ответа в вопрос: 2000,
> - просмотр флажков тревоги: 2000,
> - отсутствие проверки на спам: 750.
>
> ### Что такое граватар?
>
> Это картинка, связанная с вашей почтой, которая появляется рядом с
>   вашими сообщениями. Вы можете задать ее на сайте gravatar.com.
>
> ### Что такое визитка?
>
> Это ссылка в виде картинки на личный профиль участника на сайте с
>   кратким резюме профиля: граватаром, именем и очками уважения
>   участника. HTML-код для вставки визитки на страницу находится в личном
>   профиле участника. Например, код визитки участника Русский язык
>   выглядит так:
>
> `<a
>   href='https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1/%D0%A5%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4'><img
>   src='https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1/flair.png' title="Профиль
>   участника ХэшКод на сайте ценителей русского слова Русский
>   язык."></a>`
>
> А сама визитка выглядит так:
>
> https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1/%D0%A5%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4'>https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1/flair.png' title="Профиль
>   участника ХэшКод на сайте ценителей русского слова Русский
>   язык.">
>
> ### Могут ли другие участники править мои вопросы и ответы?
>
> Да. Это дает возможность раз за разом улучшать качество вопросов и
>   ответов. Чем больше доверие к участнику, тем больше у него
>   возможностей править сообщения.
>
> В большинстве случаев изменения сводятся к улучшению стиля, языка,
>   форматирования, то есть к повышению читаемости сообщения. Но в ряде
>   случаев случаев сообщения могут правиться настолько, что будет
>   меняться исходный смысл, заложенный первым автором.
>
> ### Что такое "общие" вопросы и ответы?
>
> Это вопросы и ответы с коллективным авторством, типа "вики". Под ними
>   нет ни имени автора, изначально задавшего вопрос, ни имени авторов,
>   внесших свой вклад в правку. Автором считается все сообщество
>   участников  сайта Русский язык. За такие вопросы и ответы не
>   начисляются и не убавляются очки уважения. Обычно это вопросы,
>   предполагающие множество ответов, например, "Список типичных ошибок" и
>   т.п.
>
> ### Забыт пароль, не срабатывает OpenID - в итоге не зайти на сайт, что делать?
>
> В случае любых затруднений со входом на сайт, можно получить
>   [ссылку](https://rus.stackexchange.com/account/tempsignin/) для временного входа на свой почтовый адрес (указанный
>   при регистрации). Войдя по присланной ссылке на сайт, в профиле можно
>   задать новый пароль или добавить новый OpenID.
>
> ### Как оставить отзыв, задать вопрос, сделать предложение по сайту?
>
> Есть несколько вариантов:
>
> - можно отправить сообщение через [форму обратной связи](https://rus.stackexchange.com/contact/);
> - или задать вопрос в на сайте [Мета](http://meta.hashcode.ru) c меткой "Русский-Язык";
> - или прокомментировать статью в дневнике.
>
> ### Как поделиться сайтом с другом?
>
> Чтобы поделиться сайтом с друзьями, товарищами, коллегами, и вообще
>   всеми, кому может быть интересно, просто опубликуйте ссылку на
>   интересный вопрос (или на сайт как таковой) в любимой социальной
>   сети, на своей странице или в своем блоге. В заметке блога: "[Как
>   поделиться сайтом с другом?](http://blog.hashcode.ru/2012/01/blog-post_05.html)" наглядно показывается, как это
>   сделать.
>
> ### У вас еще остались вопросы?
>
> Спрашивайте!

Возможно, что-то из имеющегося окажется полезным для будущей справки обновленного сообщества Русский язык.

Comment: "В чем особенность форума Русский язык?" — или "В чем особенность форума «Русский язык»?"

Answer (score 2):

> Вы можете ответить даже на свой собственный вопрос, если на самом деле приложили усилия и нашли ответ уже после того, как задали вопрос.

У меня возник вопрос, как и когда возникло в русском языке некое слово или выражение. Я порылась в Интернете и нашла ответ. 
Возможно, это будет  интересно кому-нибудь еще.
Есть ли смысл публиковать в сообществе вопрос с ответом?

Comment: Спасибо, что присоединились. А то я уж отчаялся. По поводу публикации вопроса сразу с ответом - думаю, что это не совсем правильно. Вот если вопрос возник, провисел тут некоторое время, а затем Вы сами нашли ответ - тогда можно. А если он сразу с ответом... здесь всё же не сборник фактов. Но это я так думаю, а правила мы тут стараемся написать для всех. Так что каждое мнение учтётся.

Comment: «здесь всё же не сборник фактов» — это хорошее замечание. А *что* здесь? Цель  [ru.so] — не помощь отдельным людям, а собрание базы знаний по программированию в виде вопросов и ответов. А что является целью [rus.se] (этого сообщества)?

Comment: Сборник фактов - это сообщения вроде "слон - единственное млекопитающее, которое не может прыгать". Мало того, что может, так ещё и не понятно зачем это тут. По-моему (исключительно по-моему) здесь, как и на StackOverflow сборник вопросов и ответов на них. Честно говоря, не знаю, как быть с вопросами, ответ на которые спрашивающий сам знает. Когда такое видишь - то первая мысль, что человек просто хочет, возможно не очень честно, поднять карму. Конечно, бывает, что сам находишь ответ некоторое время спустя. Но (опять-таки лично я) против вопросов, ответ на которые уже знаешь.

Comment: Обязательно публиковать. Это заложено в политику ресурса. Только учтите, что ваш ответ на ваш же вопрос совсем не обязан быть "по умолчанию" самым правильным. А "принять" его вы не сможете.

Comment: *По поводу публикации вопроса сразу с ответом - думаю, что это не совсем правильно.* - Я Вас поправлю. Если у администрации ресурса ничего не изменилось (в связи с переездом на SE, например) в понимании его функционирования, то никаких дополнительных ограничений на публикацию ответов на свои вопросы нет и быть не может. Ресурс задумывался как некая "база  знаний", куда можно попасть из поисковка, например, и найти ответ на свой вопрос, а совсем не сервис типа справочного бюро. Какая разница ищущему ответ гостю, кто это ответ дал: автор вопроса, или нет?

Comment: *«здесь всё же не сборник фактов» — это хорошее замечание.* - Именно сборник фактов, включая и те, которые можно найти и в другом месте. Только не самых уж банальных фактов, а все остальное - годится.

Comment: Ясно, тогда я этот пункт меняю.

Comment: @behemothus, вы можете принять свой ответ на свой вопрос, но не сразу. Это логично, вдруг кто-то напишет ответ лучше вашего.

Comment: @user244413. Да, согласен, Позднее - могу. Вопрос логичности - спорен. То, что не сразу, это, может, и логично, нелогично, что вообще могу. Вроде, раньше, до переезда на SE такого не было.

Answer (score 2):

Да, и еще про ответы.
Очень хорошо, если для подтверждения ответа используются ссылки. Но так как ссылки имеют свойство отмирать, желательно также скопировать относящийся к ответу текст.

Comment: Это само собой. Но FAQ по ответам - это на далекое будущее, там еще конь не валялся.

Comment: Мета-пункт: FAQ не произносить как "фак",  a эф-эй-кью |)

Comment: @ddbug, зачем нам эти англицизмы? FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions) переводится на русский как ЧаВо (ЧАсто задаваемые ВОпросы).